# How to prevent component from destroying on route change in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to show the list of products of different categories, which are retrieved from the server and cached, so when switching between categories, I don't have to make new requests every time. For that, I've used `<keep-alive></keep-alive>`, and It works partially.

```
<template>
  <div class="category">
    <h3 class="title animate-charcter"
        id="title">Choose the category</h3>
    <div class="category-container">
      <img class="category-item"
           data-cat="woman"
           @click="component = 'WomanClothes'"
           src="@/assets/hmwlogo.png">
      <img class="category-item"
           data-cat="electronics"
           @click="component = 'Electronics'"
           src="@/assets/electrologo2.jpg">
      <img class="category-item"
           data-cat="furniture"
           @click="component = 'Furniture'"
           src="@/assets/furniturelogo.png">
      <img class="category-item"
           data-cat="man"
           @click="component = 'ManClothes'"
           src="@/assets/hmmlogo.png">
    </div>

    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import WomanClothes from "./WomanClothes.vue"
  import Electronics from "./Electronics.vue"
  import Furniture from "./Furniture.vue"
  import ManClothes from "./ManClothes.vue"

  export default {
    name: "Category",
    components: { WomanClothes , Electronics , Furniture , ManClothes },
    data() {
      return {
        component: "WomanClothes"
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

So when the user clicks on one of the category items, `<component :is="component" />` dynamically updates itself. 4 other components that I've imported do API call, retrieves the data, and dynamically shows the data. The code is the same (I know it's efficient), just use different endpoints. So I will just show the code for one of them:

**WomanClothes.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="product-list-container">
    <input />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="list-item-container"
           v-for="product in products"
           :key="product.productId"
           @click="seeTheProduct(product)">
        <img :src="product.images[0].paths[0]"
             class="card-img-top"
             loading="lazy"
             alt="...">
        <div class="card-info">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-price">{{ product.price }} $.</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="load-more">
      <button v-if="loadMore"
              v-show="loadNow"
              @click="loadMoreProducts">
        Load more
      </button>
      <p v-else>End of the page</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  /* eslint-disable */
  import { db } from '../firebase';

  export default {
    name: "Products-list",
    props: {
      msg: String
    },

    data() {
      return {
        products: [],
        tempArr: [],
        path: '',
        latestDoc: null,
        loadMore: true,
        loadNow: true
      }
    },
    created() {
      console.log('from created')
      this.getProducts('products/woman-id/w-items')
    },
    destroyed() {
      console.log('on destroy')
    },
    methods: {
      loadMoreProducts() {
        this.loadNow = !this.loadNow;
        this.latestDoc = this.$store.getters.getDocHMW
        this.getProducts('products/woman-id/w-items')
      },
      async getProducts(category) {
        this.tempArr = []
        const ref = db.collection(category)
          .orderBy('price')
          .startAfter(this.latestDoc || 0)
          .limit(12)

        const data = await ref.get();

        data.docs.forEach(doc => {
          // this.tempArr.push(doc.data())
          this.products.push(doc.data())
        })

        this.latestDoc = data.docs[data.docs.length - 1];
        this.$store.commit('saveDoc', {doc: this.latestDoc, cat: 'hmw'})

        if (data.empty) {
          console.log('empty db')
          this.loadMore = false;
          this.$store.commit('saveBtnStatus', this.loadMore)
        }

        this.loadNow = true
      },
      // function to route to product info page
      seeTheProduct(product) {
        // saving to vuex and in localStorage
        this.$store.commit('checkProduct', product)
        // redirect the page
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'productinfo'
        })
      }
    },
  };
</script>
```

When `seeTheProduct` function gets called, the `destroyed` hook gets called, which means all cached data gets lost, when back to that route again. How can I make it, so when the route is being changed, the component which called for route change, doesn't get destroyed ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to specify the 'key' prop on the router-view, like this:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Then the keep-alive component will cache each component by key which evaluates to the url.

Comment: I needed to destroy the component where I'm using same component for creating & updating. When going to creating from updating it won't destroy the component (creating & updating uses different routes). But your answer fixed that